# error when running sql job that has ssis package

Tags: sql-server

I have a ssis package created in sql server 2005. I am trying to run this in sql server 2008. when I run the command "exec xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /f "C:\MyPackage.dtsx"'" I get the following error.

There was an exception while loading Script Task from XML: System.IO.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk.

I have a script task in the package and there is where it is failing. I do not visual studio 2008 to convert this package to 2008 version. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks,
sridhar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that you can run a 2005 SSIS package on a 2008 SQL Server.  If you have the install disk for SQL Server 2008 you should be able to install the Business Intelligence Development Studio which is Visual Stuido for the development of SSIS and SSRS packages.  You should then be able to use that to updgrade your package to the 2008 version.

Hope that helps, good luck.

Comment: I was able to open visual studio 2008 from sqlserver box and convert the package into 2008 version. After I converted it, it worked fine. Before conversion also I was able to run the package. But it is creating warnings in application event log and creating .tmp files in c:\users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp folder every time the job that has this package run. Now with this updated version it is not doing it.